# What's the meaning of the PHP token name T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM?

Tags: php, history

What's the story behind the `::`'s sometimes token name

```
T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

I'm mainly interested in knowing if

1. This is an abbreviation for something else.
2. This is a phrase in a language other than English, and if so what's the language and what's a rough translation.
3. This is some obscure-to-me programming term.
4. Drunk developers.

Comment: [פעמיים נקודתיים](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paamayim_Nekudotayim#PHP) ;)

Answer (score 37):

From [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

> Paamayim Nekudotayim would, at first, seem like a strange choice for naming a double-colon. However, while writing the Zend Engine 0.5 (which powers PHP 3), that's what the Zend team decided to call it. It actually does mean double-colon - in Hebrew!

Comment: _Paamayim Nekudotayim would, **at first**, seem like a strange choice for naming_

No, even knowing it's definition, it **always** seems like a strange choice.

Answer (score 4):

It's the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator).