# What is the name of the :: operator?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, and I am practicing with some online tutorials. I usually encounter the sign `::` while going through books, online tutorial or blogs. Even if I check some PHP demo applications I see this operator. I tried to put this sign in Google, but I got unexpected results. I even tried to search it in other forums as well, but I didn't got the right answer. I usually call it a bubble colon, but what is its technical name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::` is the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) (you may sometimes find references to `Paamayim Nekudotayim`, [hebrew for "double colon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588298/whats-the-meaning-of-the-php-token-name-t-paamayim-nekudotayim)). It is used to call static functions of a class, as in

```
class MyClass {
  public static function hi() {
    echo "hello, world";
  }
}
MyClass::hi();
```

For more details on classes and objects, refer to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 3):

It has the exotic name "Paamayim Nekudotayim", but you may just call it [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

Answer (score 3):

It's called scope resolution operator. More information in *[Scope Resolution Operator (::)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)* (PHP manual).

Answer (score 1):

A single one is called a colon, so you could search for "php double colon" and would find this:

> http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php
>
> Scope Resolution Operator (::)
>
> Sometimes it is useful to refer to functions and variables in base classes or to refer to functions in classes that have not yet any instances. The :: operator is being used for this.